# Expected value of Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

> **Question**: Number of errors on a test area on a disk has a Poisson
>   distribution with $λ = 0.2$. What is the expected number of errors per
>   test area?

I said number of errors is $0.2$ since expected value of Poisson Distribution just equals to $λ$. Isn't that the right answer?

Comment: seems correct to me